# What features are heavily used in C# 2.0, but is not available in VBNET 2.0, and how to workaround?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

> **I don't want a war between VB.NET and C# developers, neither is my goal to open a C# VS VB.NET confrontation.**

I would like you all to list a feature that is heavily used in C#, but is not available in VB.NET 2.0, and how would you work around to achieve a similar behaviour or purpose?

For example:

**C#**

Accepts void (return) lambda expressions. Here's an example with FNH mapping:

```
Component(x => x.Address, m => { 
    m.Map(x => x.Number); 
    m.Map(x => x.Street); 
    m.Map(x => x.PostCode); 
});
```

This is impossible to do before VB.NET 4.0 (supposed to be doable in VB.NET 4.0)

**VB.NET**

Must write a helping method (Sub), and provide the [AddressOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y72ewk2b(VS.80).aspx) this method in order to workaround.

```
Private Sub Helper(ByVal m As MType) 
    m.Map(Function(x) x.Number) 
    m.Map(Function(x) x.Street) 
    m.Map(Function(x) x.PostCode) 
End Sub 

...   
Component(Function(x) x.Address, AddressOf Helper)
```

Now I know, it is not VB.NET 2.0, but this is an example. VB.NET 3.0 and 3.5 can used too. Please just mention what version of VB.NET this refers to.

Comment: You are restricting it to VB.Net 2.0, but what about C#?? Any version or version 2.0 too?

Comment: To whom who vote to close this question, I don't get why!? I'm only inquiring on features available in C# that are not in VBNET, and if there's a workaround to achieve the objective. Isn't objective enough?

Comment: You example is not really a fair comparison as you could not do your c# example until .net 3.5

Comment: Probably because there is not single right answer, probably should be a CW

Comment: @Will: How to wiki this? I have no clue. =)

Comment: @Ben Robinson: You're right, but this is the only example I had at hand. =)

Comment: @SwDevMan81: There is a single right answer. The right answer contains all features available in C# that do not exist in VB.NET. Since C# has a finite set of features then the subset of those not available in VB.NET is also finite. Therefore, it is answerable. The subjective part is how you define a feature, but I think we all share a rigid enough definition that we could let this fly.

Comment: @Will Marcouiller, please update your post to say which version of c# you'd like to compare to VB.Net 2.0. Like @Ben Robinson, you're comparing C# 3.0 with VB.Net 2.0 (VB8 actually)

Comment: @Chris Haas: Both code samples are from .NET 3.5. It is an example only of what I figured to be the illustrated feature in C#, and the workaround in VBNET. This is just an illustration. One could understand that and provide some other example. I prefer C# and VBNET 2.0, but providing .NET 3.5 could also be useful. I just want to find a workaround so that one can easily work in VBNET (me, in occurence).

Comment: @Will edit your post, in the lower right hand corner below the edit box and above the preview there is a checkbox to make it a wiki.  Only the person who asks the question can turn it into a wiki.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could check out the [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_C_Sharp_and_Visual_Basic_.NET) for a comparison.  See sections "Features of Visual Basic .NET not found in C#" and "Features of C# not found in Visual Basic .NET".

Comment: The link is pretty interesting! =)

Comment: Yeah, they don't list workarounds for any of them.  Some of them wont have workarounds like multi-line comments (with the exception of just using a bunch of single line comments back to back).

Answer (score 7):

Iterator blocks (yield return/yield break) is probably the biggest.

Comment: The workaround is to code the IEnumerable or IEnumerator classes manually.

Answer (score 1):

For me something that I miss is implicit interface definitions:

```
ISomething
{
   void Execute();
}

class ASomething : ISomething
{
   public void Execute()
  {
    //Do something
  }
}
```

Is fine.  In VB.net you have to explicitly mark the method as implementing the interface, which I find to be quite a nuisance.  I know that there are people that prefer this technique, but not for me...

Comment: That is something I miss a lot too! It took me time to get used to it. Every now and then, to simply press [Enter] when the Implements IInterface is reported as an error, then it will automatically implement the interface, writing every "Implements IInterface.Member" required. By chance that exists! Otherwise it would be a pain! But you're right. =)

Answer (score 1):

Unsafe code block via the `unsafe` keyword are not allowed in VB.NET. There is no workaround. But, honestly, I have never used the feature anyway. If I encounter a situation that would typically require this feature I usually punt and move straight to C++/CLI.